# iOS Obj-C alloc init issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this following class. Name it as "file.h"

```
@interface ValidationResult : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL success;
@end

@interface Validator : NSObject
+ (ValidationResult *)validateEmail:(NSString*)inputString isRequiredField:(BOOL)isRequiredField;
@end
```

In file.m

```
@implementation Validator

+ (ValidationResult *)validateEmail:(NSString*)inputString isRequiredField:(BOOL)isRequiredField{
ValidationResult *validationResult;

if (inputString.length == 0) {
    if(isRequiredField){
        validationResult.success = false;
        return validationResult;
    }else{
        validationResult.success = true;
        return validationResult;
    }
}
@end
```

I have problem in this following code

```
 ValidationResult *validationResult = [[ValidationResult alloc] init];
```

The above code gives me this error when compiling the project

```
Apple Linker Mach-O error. "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ValidationResult", referenced from:
```

what is wrong with it? I always create new object using such code and everything is fine. Only for this particular class doesn't go well.

Any idea?? Thanks!

Comment: can u show me your full code of .m file?

Comment: the full code implementation in .m file has been added

Comment: I See no @implementation for `ValidationResult`. Add that and you will be fine I believe.

Comment: Seems you no need to create object, directly use class name to call class method.

Comment: By the way, you can simplify your condition to just `validationResult.success = !isRequiredField; return validationResult;`;

Comment: Please check my answer, @Alvin

Comment: Same question asked and Edited With wrong code , now how your code worked with this answer below `ValidationResult *validationResult = [[ValidationResult alloc] init];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Interface` should have the following `@implementation` in `.m file`

```
@interface ValidationResult : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL success;
@end

@interface Validator : NSObject
+ (ValidationResult *)validateEmail:(NSString*)inputString isRequiredField:(BOOL)isRequiredField;
@end
```

**.m File**

```
@implementation ValidationResult
@end

@implementation Validator
    + (ValidationResult *)validateEmail:(NSString*)inputString isRequiredField:(BOOL)isRequiredField{
        ValidationResult *validationResult = [[ValidationResult alloc] init];

    if (inputString.length == 0) {
        if(isRequiredField){
            validationResult.success = false;
            return validationResult;
        }else{
            validationResult.success = true;
            return validationResult;
        }
    }
@end
```

Comment: works like a charm! thanks Sir! Didn't know that each interface should have its own implementation on .m file

Comment: Happy coding.. :)

Comment: @LalKrishna explain a little in your answer why your code works.  more about this particular line " ValidationResult *validationResult = [[ValidationResult alloc] init];".